# What is the blue/grey balloon on Happy Street?

Tags: happy-street

Above the toy shop there are balloons and every now and then I see a blue/grey balloon with a pink item attached. When I ask people they say it is a deer but I believe it is a dinosaur eating something. What is this balloon?

Comment: Do you have a picture of it?

Answer (score -1):

It's the developer Godzi Lab's logo.